# How to use Views to obtain this?

Tags: 7, views

I want to use the Views module to obtain the number of comments associated to a node, and show it as "1 comment," "5 comments."
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [Views Group By](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_groupby) module, this will do it. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... enriches Views2 functionality with SQL Grouping and Aggregation capabilities.
>
> A new field group: SQL Aggregation is added, in Views, once you install the module. The field group has one available field: SQL Aggregation: Group By Fields. The field allows to configure many aspects of "group by" SQL clause and "count()" fields.

Comment: Or native group by in Views 3.